# Disable 'General' group sales in Magento

Tags: magento, checkout

I'm looking to disable sales on our Magento site for any customers in the 'General' customer group. We have a tiered customer group system setup, with different tax rules etc., but I can't figure out how to disable 'general' as a group that can purchase from the site. I don't want new customers signing up able to purchase without being assigned a group first.

Thanks.

Comment: At the BuyNow button, use a condition like, if the LoggedIn Customer is not in the required category, then it shouldnt display the button

Comment: Thanks Pavan, where do I access that option in the CMS? IS it similar to adding a cart rule?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my idea: set up observer on `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index` event, which will fire before checkout page is loaded. In observer we check if customer belongs to certain group and if so we redirect him to cart page and show error message.

Translated to Magento code, it would look like this:

Firs we hook on the event in our `config.xml`

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index>
            <observers>
                <your_module>
                    <class>your_module/observer</class>
                    <method>banCheckout</method>
                </your_module>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_onepage_index>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

and in our observer:

```
public function banCheckout(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $customerSession = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
    if (!$customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
        return $this;
    }

    $groupId = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
    if ($groupId == 1) {
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError(
            Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Your error message.')
        );
        $action = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction();
        $action->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart'));
        $action->setFlag('', Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Keep in mind this is just an example, and a pretty simple one.